# Left click causes pointer lag on iMac, without magnet or bettertouchtool

Tags: imac, mouse, games, cursor

I have been having some little issues with my 2019 Sonoma 14.3.1 iMac. When I click the left button of the mouse, it causes the pointer to freeze for half a second. It is making the gaming experience I play a game where you need 15 cps) miserable.

Tests and facts:

1.) I tried to change every mouse settings

2.) I tried changing the main click and it is always the button on the left that lags

3.) the right button work perfectly

4.) using a different mouse gives the same issues

5.) using a trackpad gives the same issues

6.) this issue is valid out of my session ( the selection screen, my dad, mom account)

7.) I don’t have bettertouchtool or magnet

8.) I tried resetting Nvram and VRAM, didn’t solve the issue

9.) I tried restarting my IMac, didn’t solve the issue

10.) I tried using the Magic Mouse, same issues

11.) I don’t have any malware

12.) When using a different mouse to click and aim, there isn’t issues

13.) My parents have currently logged out of their session

I have been trying to solve this issue for a while and then tried searching for a solution on the internet, they all said that it is magnet or bettertouchtool but I don’t have any windows snapping devices.

Comment: Does it only happen with the game, which you also appear to have ruled out without saying so? What is the game, how is it provisioned, Steam, GoG, etc? Have you ruled out any Steam Input issues for instance?

Comment: I play Minecraft, mainly 1.8.9. Which requires spam clicking. The issue does not only happen in Minecraft, if I look at the pointer closely on my desktop, the pointer lags back a bit when I click, it may seem irrelevant but in Minecraft it is decisive

Comment: News: The problem isn’t the left click, it’s the left button, of any mouse connected to the IMac, when I bind the left button to anything, clicking the mouse button lags. So if I bind any key to left click, no lag. Conclusion: the left click has no problem, the problem is clicking the button situated at the left of a mouse.

Comment: when I click the left button of my mouse, my pointer/cursor lags but there’s no fps drop